# get variable from json

Tags: php, jquery

i have this:

```
{"sliders":{"c1":{"content":[{"title":1,"content_type":"image_content"}]}}}
```

i can get the title using the code below:

```
$decoded = json_decode($list[$i]['info'],true);
$json = $decoded['sliders']['c1']['content'][0]);
                $x = $json['title'];
                echo $x;
```

when i am trying to get the content_type...

```
$y = $json['content_type'];
                echo $y;
```

...then it shows me undefined index error..why this happens?

Comment: `var_dump($json)` after the decode to see what you're working with. Not to mention that you've got a syntax error.

Comment: i can see an array which include title and content_type so i guess is correct but i realize that i cant get the string type..the title appears because it's an integer.. :/

Comment: When I test your code, minus the syntax error, it works just fine. Returns "1image_content" when echoing `$x` and `$y`. Is this the only code you have? [EXAMPLE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/qvfs-1yqb)

Answer (score 1):

First of all: The statement…

```
$json = $decoded['sliders']['c1']['content'][0]);
```

…should have given a syntax error for the excessive right bracket **`)`**

A var_dump of *$decoded* shows this:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["sliders"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["c1"]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
      ["content"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
          ["title"]=>
          int(1)
          ["content_type"]=>
          string(13) "image_content"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, the entire variable *$decoded* is **an object** of objects.
The object *content* is **an array** of one (in this case) object: *content[0]*.

Therefore you would access the two items like this - using the **object** and **array** notation where appropriate:

```
echo $decoded->sliders->c1->content[0]->title;
echo $decoded->sliders->c1->content[0]->content_type;
```

OR

```
$json = $decoded->sliders->c1->content[0];
echo $json->title;
echo $json->content_type;
```

…which both would give:

```
1
image_content
```